# Google iot core connection status

Tags: mqtt, iot, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

I am using Google IOT core with mongoose os. I wanted to update device connection status to firestore. But i am unable to find event which reports mqtt connection status to pub/sub like when device disconnects or reconnect i.e if device is offline or not.

I am stuck on this problem for days.Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

As @devunwired mentioned [in this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54609757/google-core-iot-device-offline-event-or-connection-status) it is now possible to monitor Stackdriver logs for disconnect events. You must have at a minimum enabled INFO level logging on your project in IoT Core > Registries > [your registry] > Edit Registry > Select "Info" log level > Click save.

**Original Response**

There are a few values you can look at that are tracked in device configuration metadata that you could use to know when a device last was online:

1. Last Configuration Send time - sent anytime your device connects / 
   configuration is posted
2. Last Event Time - Last time an event was sent from the device
3. Last State Time - Last time state was sent from the device
4. Last Heartbeat time - Last time MQTT heartbeat was sent

To get you started, [here is an example using API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/cloudiot/v1/cloudiot.projects.locations.registries.devices.get) that you can fill-in with your project ID, region, registry, and device to query for a specific device's metadata.

For 1...3 you have control over these through device manager and by publishing data. MQTT heartbeat is updated if your device sends an `MQTT_PINGREQ` message during the "ping period" without other messages getting sent.

At any rate, you could use any of these update time values to see the last time a device was online / functioning.  You could query the states of your devices after listing the devices in a registry and could update a Firebase RTDB periodically if that's how you want to report (e.g. using AppEngine TaskQueue). Note that you also just can get these "last connected" values from the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iot/).

It was said before but we don't have an event for disconnect, just configuration ack, which generally is the connection event. If you want to share state between a device and the device manager, use [state messages](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/devices#device_state).

Comment: Thanks i think this may work. I am unable to access google iot v1beta1 api. https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta1 whenever i try this discovery api this shows Discovery document not found for API service. Can you please help

Comment: My bad, I need to update those samples to instead use v1 (we're moving on from v1beta1).

Comment: Sorry to ask a another question in comment, I just wanted to know how to send iot config messages from firebase function with qos 0. I could not find anything in docs.

Comment: @HonneyGoyal might be worth asking another question but you could use the NodeJS manager example ensuring you add the dependencies in package.json for your cloud function.

Comment: We shouldn't have to do something like this just check if a device is online .. it's as simple as an MQTT connect/disconnect but i'm finding more and more how incomplete Google's IoT functionality is .. which makes it difficult to just use core iot and firebase without having to write a bunch of helper functions for basic iot stuff

Comment: @class How is this still not something available?  All other IoT providers have some way of doing this?  So we literally have to constantly run a fn to check based on those values, instead of just adding LWT support or some kind of event on MQTT disconnect?  I can't believe we have to jump through this many hoops just for device offline state!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no built in way to do this right now as there aren't events on this state.

However, you could implement a hack by sending a message on connect/disconnect from the device that you have a Cloud Function subscribed to the Pub/Sub topic listening for. It's not perfect as it would fail in the case where the device disconnected unexpectedly.

Comment: Does any other cloud iot service has this option like aws or azure.

Comment: I don't know offhand. I work at Google, so I'm not as familiar with their systems. I did a quick look at AWS' events, and I don't see one for connect/disconnect, but I definitely could just be missing it in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no way to do this, that i've been able to find (a year later after this original post).  I posted a question here on SO regarding this as well, with more details and link to example code I had to use for handling this:
[Google Core IoT Device Offline Event or Connection Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54609757/google-core-iot-device-offline-event-or-connection-status)

Answer (score -1):

The AWS IoT platform publishes messages on a special MQTT topic (prefixed with `$aws`) when your device connects/disconnects. You can easily use these to monitor these events - however, you should be aware that the MQTT protocol is designed to be robust to a poor networking conditions and the broker on the AWS side probably doesn't think it's a bit deal to disconnect a client. The broker expects that the client will just reconnect and queue messages for a moment during that process (which can be a big deal on a microcontroller).

All that being said, the AWS topics you would watch are:

```
$aws/events/presence/connected/{clientId}
```

and

```
$aws/events/presence/disconnected/{clientId}
```

and the documentation for these (and other) lifecycle events are located: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html

Comment: The question is about the Google Cloud IoT platform, it's not about AWS.

Comment: Huh, hard to believe I wrote a response for the completely wrong platform.  Weird.